# Adobe AEM WorkFlow activate a page including child pages

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I want to activate a page also include it's child pages using workflow
like below

Parent Node

```
・Child Node 1
・Child Node 2
・Child Node 3
```

Requirement is:
Is it possible ??? Please give solution also in comment......
thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Replicator](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Replicator.html) api to activate the pages.

In your workflow process step. You can do the following

`currentPage = getCurrentPagePath(); // this is something which you have to figure out, this depends on your workflow code i.e how exactly your workflow got triggere`d.

Now,

```
Iterator<Page> childPages = currentPage.listChildren();
```

Now iterate over the child pages and for each child page, do the following

```
replicator.replicate(session,repplicationActionType, childPagePath);
```

You can get the instance of replicator using OSGi dependency injection.

```
@Reference
public Replicator replicator
```

Comment: thank you very much, can you tell how activate  a page use ecmascript,
just like above java source?